# How to get data from .xml file

Tags: xml, windows, vbscript

I am new to programming, so wanted to ask a question, because this problem stopped my work fro a while...
I have an .xml file (below is a fragment):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<JAMonXML>
...................................
<row rowID="3"> 
<Modify>3</Modify> 
<Label>/registration/app/main, ms.</Label> 
<Hits>2</Hits> 
<Avg>1,164</Avg> 
<Total>2,327</Total> 
<StdDev>13</StdDev> 
<LastValue>1,154</LastValue> 
<Min>1,154</Min> 
<Max>1,173</Max> 
<Active>0</Active> 
<AvgActive>1</AvgActive> 
<MaxActive>1</MaxActive> 
<FirstAccess>5/8/13 2:21:40 PM</FirstAccess> 
<LastAccess>5/8/13 2:21:41 PM</LastAccess> 
<Enabled>true</Enabled> 
<Primary>false</Primary> 
<HasListeners>false</HasListeners> 
</row>
.......................
</JAMonXML>
```

I need to get a value, named LastValue: 1,154 in this time.
I have a Windows computer, so I need to have a VBScript to do this and to get 1,154 as a result of running this script

I will be very pleased, if you could help me solving this problem!

Answer (score 0):

It works now! :D

```
Dim xmlDoc, objNodeList, plot

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.load("C:\...\jamon.xml")
Set objNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("LastValue")

If objNodeList.length > 0 then
For each x in objNodeList
plot=x.Text
msgbox plot
Next
Else
msgbox chr(34) & "LastValue" & chr(34) & " not found."
End If
```